# Which apt-get package of java do I install if I want to use elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

```
sudo apt-get install XXX?
```

What java package should I install?

Comment: Here is someone installing elasticsearch with a strange way of installing a deb package: https://gist.github.com/wingdspur/2026107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [debian package](http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.5.deb) of elasticsearch it will depend on the java package it needs and install it automatically when you're installing elasticsearch.